# What are the valid symbol names for packages?

Tags: packages, variable

Regarding to the message:

```
Needs::cxt: Invalid context specified at position 1 in 
Needs[foo-package`,/path-to-foo/foo-package.wl]. 
A context must consist of valid symbol names separated by and ending with `
```

.

What are the valid symbol names for packages? Where I can find a documentation for this? I know empirically that "-" and "_" are forbidden.

Comment: The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicObjects.html#11134) says "The name of a symbol must be a sequence of letters, letter‐like forms, and digits, not starting with a digit. Uppercase and lowercase letters are always distinguished in the Wolfram Language."

Comment: There is also some discussion of ["letter-like forms"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html).

Comment: To expand on what @ilian said, a context name is part of the full name of a symbol, thus the same rules apply. When you write a single-file package, the file name should be identical to the context name (plus the extension)

Comment: Also, `$` is allowed too in names.

Comment: @ilian You answered it.